# How to maximize multiply operations?

Tags: python, algorithm

The question is as follows.

```
There are two operators:
operator1: adds x to current number
operator2: multiplies current number by y
where the values of x an y are given and fixed. The starting number is 1 and the goal is to get to number t by sequentially applying operator1 and operator2. You have to maximize the number of times you use operator2. For maximum usage of operator 2, you have to minimize the number of times you use operator 1.

Constraints: 
1 <= x <= 1000
2 <= y <= 1000
1 <= t <= 10^20

Input: t, x, y
Output is the number of operator2. If there is no solution, return null

Sample input 1: 
t = 54
x = 1
y = 3
Sample output: 3
Explanation: ((1 + 1) times 3^3) = 54
Operator2 can be used maximally 3 times because 3^4 > 54. For operator2 being used three times, operator1 needs to be used at least once because 3^3 is not equal to 54.

Sample input 2: 
t = 3
x = 4
y = 4
Sample output: null    

Sample input 3: 
t = 2000000000000
x = 1
y = 2
Sample output: 40
```

Personally I feel that we should solve it using dynamic programming (DP). But I can't write out detailed code.

update: The below is the DP code I implemented. It works well when t is small, but it failed very probably due to OOM when t is very large.

```
def max_multiply(t, x, y):
    dp = [None]*(t+1)
    
    dp[1] = (0, 0)  # (num_op1, num_op2)
    
    for i in range(2, t+1):
        if i-x >=0 and dp[i-x]:
            prev = dp[i-x]
            if dp[i] is None:
                dp[i] = (prev[0]+1, prev[1])
            else:
                dp[i] = max(dp[i], (prev[0]+1, prev[1]), key=lambda v: v[1]-v[0])
                
        if i%y ==0 and dp[i//y]:
            prev = dp[i//y]
            if dp[i] is None:
                dp[i] = (prev[0], prev[1]+1)
            else:
                dp[i] = max(dp[i], (prev[0], prev[1]+1), key=lambda v: v[1]-v[0])
                
    return dp[t][1] if dp[t] else None
```

Comment: Yes, dynamic programming. Why would that not work for you? What is the problem?

Comment: @trincot, hi, I tried DP and it works when t is small. But it failed when t is very large. I added one more sample input: t = 2000000000000, x = 1, y = 2. Could you help it out?

Comment: What does "failed" mean? Wrong results? Infinite loop? Error? Please provide your code and the input for which it fails, and what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: @trincot, I updated the post and added my DP code.

Comment: Please provide the input for which it fails, and what the failure is (Error? Infinite loop? Wrong returned value?), and what the expected output is.

Comment: it was automatically killed by system for sample input 3. I ran it in Jupyter Lab.

Comment: What is the expected output? 39?

Comment: yes, the output should be 39 for sample input 3

Comment: Hint: can you come up with a way to transform a sequence of operations into a different sequence that produces the same result, but where all instances of operation 2 are at the start and all instances of operation 1 are at the end? What does this tell you about the numbers you can form? Can you use this to try less sequences?

Comment: (39 doesn't look right for sample input 3. Is there a constraint missing from the problem statement?)

Comment: @user2357112, you are right, it is 40 instead of 39.  I am sorry I mixed up with another test case where t = 1000000000000, x = 1, y = 2.

Comment: @trincot, please note that the correct answer is 40 (not 39) for sample input 3.

Answer (score 0):

I revised my DP code which starts from t instead of 1. I use the stack which searches multiply operation first in a greedy manner.

It is working so far for all test cases.

```
def max_multiply(t, x, y):

    stack = [(t, (0, 0))]

    while stack:
        t1, (op1, op2) = stack.pop()

        if t1 == 1:
            return op2

        if t1 - x >= 1:
            stack.append((t1 - x, (op1+1, op2)))
        if t1%y == 0:
            stack.append((t1//y, (op1, op2+1)))

    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, its running fast on big inputs(under 0.005 sec) but it still doesn't giving full marks in the question. Can anyone do it better.

PS: we need to sequentially output the operations used till we get the 't' and if any operator is used multiple times continuously then output the number of times it was used.

```
import time

def maximize_operator_usage(t, x, y):
    operations = []

    while t > 1:
        count_operator2 = 0
        while t % y == 0:
            t //= y
            count_operator2 += 1
    
  
        if count_operator2 > 0:
             operations.append(f"operator_multiply {count_operator2}")
    
    
        count_operator1 = 0
        while t > x and t % y != 0:
            t -= x
            count_operator1 += 1
    
        if count_operator1 > 0:
            operations.append(f"operator_add {count_operator1}")
    
        if count_operator1 == 0 and count_operator2 == 0:
            return ["no_solution"]
 
    return operations[::-1]


start = time.time()
print(maximize_operator_usage(54,1,3))
end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also tried in this way. But either of them (yours and mine) is very inefficient for some edge cases, for example, t = 2000000000000, x = 1, y = 2000000000000 + 1. I believe there should be more other edge cases we have not considered appropriately.

Comment: I also thought about that case when y > t but the catch is the limit on y is 2<=y<=1000 so it wont be inefficient when t is 999 and y is 1000. Because we will be running for max 999 times if x=1 in that case

Comment: Right, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: But you code has a bug, for example t = 28, x = 2, y = 3 or t = 3, x = 4, y = 4. Your code does not ensure that t reaches 1 finally.

Comment: For  t = 28, x = 2, y = 3 or t = 3, x = 4, y = 4, code should output,there is no solution. In other words we can't reach t = 28 if we starts from t=1 or vice vera(my approach). Working fine for me.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment after a few days. You are right for these 2 cases. But I still think it is not working for some edge cases, for example: t = 15, x = 14, y = 5, we can use one add operation to reach t = 15, but because your code is greedy to calculate multiply operations: t/y = 3, then 3 cannot reach 1 by either add or multiply operation. That is why I think a simply algorithm that calculates multiply operations in a greedy manner cannot handle some edge cases.

Comment: Note that my code using stack can handle this edge case (t = 15, x = 14, y = 5). But I am not sure if there are other edge cases it cannot handle.